# Grails criteria, how to scape property

Tags: hibernate, grails, scope, criteria

Domain involved:

```
class QuestionarioQuestao {

Questionario questionario
Questao questao
```

The criteria function inside domain class:

```
 QuestionarioQuestao.createCriteria().list(){
            **questao{eq("topico", Topico.get(1))}**
            eq("questionario", QuestionarioQuestao.get(1))
            order ("ordem", "desc")
            maxResults(1)
            projections {property("ordem")}
        }
```

It's trying to call() questao thinking its a closure, I don't know.
I've tried scape with quotes 'questao', but still...

```
 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - No signature of method: static questionariouab.Questao.call()~
```

thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
delegate.questao { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've to do this, otherwise it will always try to call a closure:

```
 **static** def getOrdem(**vquestao**, vquestionario){
    def ordem = QuestionarioQuestao.createCriteria().list(){
        questao{
            topico{
                eq("id", **vquestao**.topico.id)
```